# Angularjs Combo box value form submit

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, laravel-5

This is my angular combobox

```
<select ui-select2 id="UserID" name="UserID" ng-model="userObjs.UserID"
        data-placeholder="UserID" required style="width: 100%;">
    <option value="">Select Agent</option>
    <option ng-repeat="(key, userObj) in userObjs"
            ng-value="userObj.id"
            value="@{{userObj.id}}" >@{{userObj.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

while submitting this form to laravel controller

```
$UserID= $request->UserID;
```

it showing  `number:33` , but actual User Id is `33`, how to get only integer by avoing `number:` to the variable $UserID

Comment: before submit check data at front-end side what you are getting?

Comment: it displaying only 33. @JadavPalak

Comment: can you show your laravel model?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `track by` argument to the `ng-repeat`:

```
<select ui-select2 id="UserID" name="UserID" ng-model="userObjs.UserID"
        data-placeholder="UserID" required style="width: 100%;">
    <option value="">Select Agent</option>
    <o̶p̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶n̶g̶-̶r̶e̶p̶e̶a̶t̶=̶"̶(̶k̶e̶y̶,̶ ̶u̶s̶e̶r̶O̶b̶j̶)̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶u̶s̶e̶r̶O̶b̶j̶s̶"̶
    <option ng-repeat="(key, userObj) in userObjs track by userObj.id"
            ng-value="userObj.id"
            value="@{{userObj.id}}" >@{{userObj.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```